# Map actors and their movie onto a dictionary

Tags: python

```
def parse_actor_data(actor_data):
    while 1:
        line = actor_data.readline().strip()
        if line.count('-') > 5:
            break
    actor_movie = {}
    values = []
    actor_name = ''
    running_list = []
    movie = []
    for line in actor_data:
        position = line.find(')')
        running = line[:position + 1]
        value = running.split('\t')
        for k in value:
            if k != '':
                running_list.append(k)
        actor_name_list = value[0].split(',')
        actor_name = actor_name_list[0] + actor_name_list[-1]
        for i in range(len(running_list)):
            if value[0] == running_list[i]:
                position2 = i
        movie = running_list[position2+1:]
        actor_movie[actor_name] = movie
        check = actor_movie.keys()
    for c in range(len(check)):
        if len(check[c]) < 1:
            actor_movie.pop(check[c])
    return actor_movie
```

Problem I'm having now is that only the first item of movie is added into the actor_movie anyone can help? i tried so long for this already i seriously have no idea why isn't this working...

Comment: A sample of the data you're parsing would be helpful..

Comment: you need some debug prints.  print actor_name right after you set it. if actor_movie only has one item, you either only go through the for loop once, or you keep getting actor_name to be the same value each iteration

Answer (score 1):

Every time you run:

```
actor_movie[actor_name] = movie
```

you're overwriting the last movie that was associated with that actor. Try something like this instead where you're storing a list of movies, not just a single value:

```
try:
    actor_movie[actor_name].append(movie)
except KeyError:
    actor_movie[actor_name] = [movie]
```

There are other ways (`defaultdict`, `dict.setdefault`, etc.) to do the same thing but that should get you up and running.